# WF4 While activity condition in code

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I am building a workflow in my code, and I don't know how I can add a simple (While) condition. Tried to figure out how, but no luck with it, search on the internet but no luck either.

This is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
ActivityBuilder ab = new ActivityBuilder();
ab.Implementation = new Sequence()
{
  Variables = 
  {
     new Variable<int>("StepNo", 0)
  },

  Activities =
  {
    new While()
    {
      Condition = <the_condition>

      Body = 
      {
        //Some logic here and the StepNo is increased
      }
    }
  }   
}
```

The While condition should be something like "StepNo < 10". Any idea how can this be made?

Comment: Pick up [Pro WF: Windows Workflow in .NET 4.0](http://www.amazon.com/Pro-WF-Windows-Workflow-Experts/dp/1430227214).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var stepNo = new Variable<int>("stepNo", 0);

var activity = new Sequence
{
    Variables = 
    {
        stepNo
    },

    Activities = 
    {
        new While
        {
            Condition = new LessThan<int,int,bool>
            {
                Left = stepNo,
                Right = 10
            },

            Body = new Sequence
            {
                Activities = 
                {
                    new Assign<int>
                    {
                        To = stepNo,
                        Value = new Add<int, int, int>
                        {
                            Left = stepNo,
                            Right = 1
                        }
                    },

                    new WriteLine
                    { 
                        Text = new VisualBasicValue<string>("\"Step: \" & stepNo") 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Or a version without [expression activities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.expressions.aspx) but only with [VisualBasicValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782058.aspx), which is also an activity:

```
var stepNo = new Variable<int>("stepNo", 0);

var activity = new Sequence
{
    Variables = 
    {
        stepNo
    },

    Activities = 
    {
        new While
        {
            Condition = new VisualBasicValue<bool>("stepNo < 10"),

            Body = new Sequence
            {
                Activities = 
                {
                    new Assign<int>
                    {
                        To = stepNo,
                        Value = new VisualBasicValue<int>("stepNo + 1")
                    },

                    new WriteLine
                    { 
                        Text = new VisualBasicValue<string>("\"Step: \" & stepNo") 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi @Jota, the OP of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926041/while-activity-code-condition-in-wf4) has a very similar problem to yours, would you look at this if you get a moment? Thanks.