# While activity code condition in WF4

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

When the following is executed, the `while` loop never ends. I'm calling a method to get the value for the while loop condition here. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Activities;
    using System.Activities.Statements;
    using System.IO;

   namespace BuildActivities
    {
   public sealed class CheckFile : CodeActivity
     {

    public InArgument<string> DirectoryName;

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        Activity workflow = new Sequence
        {
            Activities =
            {
                new While
            {

                Condition = GetValue() ,

                Body = new Sequence
                {
                    Activities = {
                        new WriteLine
                            {
                                Text = "Entered"
                            },
                        new WriteLine
                            {
                                Text = "Iterating"
                            },
                            new Delay
                            {
                Duration = System.TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:01")

                            }
                    }
                }

                //Duration = System.TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:01")
            },
            new WriteLine()
            {
                Text = "Exited"
            }
        }
        };
        try
        {
            WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(workflow, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        }
        catch (TimeoutException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The File still exist. Build Service has not picked up the file.");
        }
    }


    public bool GetValue()
    {
        bool matched = false;
        matched = File.Exists(@"\\vw189\release\buildservice\conshare.txt");
        return matched;
    }

}
```

}

when the code executes, i think it is only checking the while condition for one time. because, i have written some writeline to check how it works. and i see the loop never ends. I test this by deleting the file in the folder when the loop is running. There is a service which should pick the file every 5 sec. this is to determine whether that service is up and running or not.

Comment: As per our conversation on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8066545/472495), this is quite similar (though I don't know if it is a duplicate). Would you outline why that solution hasn't worked for you?

Comment: this is the same question. while loop is not working. i mean it is not checking the condition for every iteration and hence it is looping for ever. i think the declaration of condition in while loop is wrong. i'm not sure about the problem.

Comment: Well, I fail to see something changing inside the while loop so I doubt the condition ever change to false. Show us the GetValue code and the rest of the workflow if possible.

Comment: please see above. i have updated full code.

Comment: Hi @Jota, could you please let me know what i have done wrong in setting up the condition for while activity? the condition never changed to false. is there any other way to set the condition for the boolean values?

Comment: I don't know WF4, but are you able to print out the value of `$matched` for each iteration?

Comment: i'm able to print out the matched value for each iteration and the value is true all the time. if i delete the file, it should give a matched value as false but it is not. and GetVal() method is called only one time before the sequence activity runs. it is using the same value through out the loop.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Why are you calling a workflow inside a CodeActivity? As the name suggests a CodeActivity serves to execute a peace of code. I can try to help you but I can't really understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, I don't understand what you're doing but having a workflow call inside a CodeActivity is wrong. I'll try to give you some options.

**Option 1:**

Having a `CodeActivity` which returns a boolean indicating if a file exists or not is the standard/correct way. Then you can use this activity on your workflow:

```
public sealed class CheckFile : CodeActivity<bool>
{
    public InArgument<string> FilePath { get; set; }

    protected override bool Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        return File.Exists(FilePath.Get(context));
    }
}
```

**Options 2:**

Going along with your code, you would call `File.Exists()` through [InvokeMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.invokemethod.aspx):

```
var workflow = new Sequence
{
    Activities =
    {
        new While
        {
            Condition = new InvokeMethod<bool>
            {
                TargetType = typeof (File),
                MethodName = "Exists",
                Parameters = { new InArgument<string>("c:\\file.txt") }
            },
            Body = new WriteLine {Text = "File still exists..."}
        },
        new WriteLine {Text = "File deleted."}
    }
};
```

PS: Your `GetValue` is called only once when workflow is build and evaluated just before being run by `WorkflowInvoker`. If you want it to be *dynamic* use activities like InvokeMethod like I showed you above. Again, don't try to use workflows just because, specially inside a CodeActivity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. it worked. i have used the first option. coming to the second option i have a question. so, we should not declare the workflow inside the code activities correct? so can we just leave them in a method without inheriting any activity? like native activity?